# Some files in my github repo are not listed when I go to "Got to Files"

Tags: git, github

This a github repo I am currently working on: https://github.com/opendata-swiss/ckanext-switzerland-ng
I want to link to a certain file in their : https://github.com/opendata-swiss/ckanext-switzerland-ng/blob/master/solr/solrconfig.xml

The link does not show the file I am expecting.

When I go to the repo the file is there, but when I do "go to file" on the repo the file is not listed: see here: https://github.com/opendata-swiss/ckanext-switzerland-ng/find/master

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I "go to file" at https://github.com/opendata-swiss/ckanext-switzerland-ng/find/master and start typing '`solr`', I do see the `solrconfig.xml` as expected:

[image: solr present]